# Ionic error while building

Tags: javascript, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using the ionic beta and I try to build the standard tab app (created with: `ionic start appname tabs --v2`) to test it on android just to see what the native components look like on a device. I  built a cordova android app before and it did work on my device. But I want the native components of the ionic beta but the command `ionic build android` does return this:

```
(node:2390) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not             supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a        more recent version.

Running 'build:before' gulp task before build
[08:51:38] Starting 'clean'...
[08:51:38] Finished 'clean' after 49 ms
[08:51:38] Starting 'build'...
[08:51:38] Starting 'sass'...
[08:51:38] Starting 'html'...
[08:51:38] Starting 'fonts'...
[08:51:38] Starting 'scripts'...
[08:51:38] Finished 'scripts' after 47 ms
[08:51:38] Finished 'html' after 51 ms
[08:51:38] Finished 'fonts' after 60 ms
[08:51:39] Finished 'sass' after 925 ms
[08:51:46] Finished 'build' after 8.77 s
[08:51:46] Starting 'build:before'...
[08:51:46] Finished 'build:before' after 5.09 μs

Caught exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
at Object.run   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/build.js:29:32)
at Promise.apply (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:1078:26)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:1304:14
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) 

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

I found the line in the build.js:

```
var rawArgs = rawCliArguments.slice(0);
```

But I don't know why the slice property is undefined ...

I tried nearly every version of node with the "n CLI" and I also tried re-installing cordova, ionic and node but it didn't help.
If I build the ionic v2 project via `cordova build android` it returns a .apk but after installing it only shows a white screen.

Informations from `ionic info`:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.7
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.26
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.16
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.2.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1 Build version 7B91b
```

I'm really frustrated about that, I hope somebody can help me.

Edit:
Even if I use `ionic serve` some components aren't working in the browser. For example the ionic grid layout (http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-explicit) with 5 rows and 4 cols does only show one col.

Comment: I'm having same error after updating ionic and Cordova. ionic serve not listening to sass changes and reporting setup deprecated.

Comment: FWIW, its not that `slice` is undefined, its that `rawCliArguments` is undefined, therefore has no slice method associated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can now build the project without issue. By just updating to the latest beta `sudo npm install -g ionic@beta`

Found the issue reported here: [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6735)

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day! Kind of lucky that they fixed it just yesterday haha. Do you have any idea how to fix the problem with the grid layout?